# Prove or disprove: $\left\{ \sigma\in S_{X}\mid\sigma\left(Y\right)\subseteq Y\right\}$ is a subgroup of $S_X$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $X$ be a set and $Y\subseteq X$ a non-empty subset.
Define $S_{X}=\left\{ f:X\longrightarrow X\mid f\text{ is bijective}\right\}$, $\sigma\left(Y\right)=\left\{ \sigma\left(y\right)\mid y\in Y\right\}$, $H=\left\{ \sigma\in S_{X}\mid\sigma\left(Y\right)\subseteq Y\right\}$

Prove or disprove: $H$ is a subgroup of $S_X$.

Everything seems to be be pretty straightforward, the only thing is that I'm not sure about the existence of $\sigma^{-1}$.

Comment: Well, have you tried anything?

Comment: Please provide context in an [edit]. Your question is likely to be closed and downvoted otherwise.

Comment: Why $S_X$ is a group?

Comment: Isn't this trivial?  H is simply defined to be elements of $S_x$ with some special property.

Comment: That's not the usual definition of $S_X$. As you wrote it, $S_X$ won't be, in general, a group.

Comment: Your definition of $S_X$ is not standard.

Comment: $f$ needs to be injective **and surjective**

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change it, fixing it now.

Comment: Are you given finiteness of any of the sets?  If not, I can think of an example of $X = \mathbb{Z}$, $Y = \mathbb{N}$, and $\sigma : n \mapsto n + 1$ where $\sigma$ fixes $Y$ but $\sigma^{-1}$ does not.  (So, in order for the statement to be true, I think you need $Y$ to be finite.)

Comment: It looks like the statement should also be true if $X \setminus Y$ is finite.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, $H$ is not closed under inversion in general.

Take $X=\mathbb{Q}$, $Y=\mathbb{Z}$, and $\sigma(x)=2x$. Then, $\sigma \in H$ (because twice any integer is an integer), but $\sigma^{-1} \notin H$ (because $\frac{1}{2}$ is a non-integer rational number that becomes an integer when doubled).